# event manager wordpress plugin booking form shortcode not working

Tags: php, wordpress, events

i am using event manager version 3.0.97 , i want to use booking form in my custon page.
i am using old version because i have customized things.

```
#_ADDBOOKINGFORM
```

i tried

```
echo do_shortcode('[#_ADDBOOKINGFORM]'); 
echo do_shortcode('#_ADDBOOKINGFORM');
```

even i called the function.

```
em_add_booking_form() ;
```

but no luck. 
what am i doing wrong ?

Note: i have customized things that's why i am not using latest version.

thanks

Answer (score 4):

This maybe old but hoping this help other DEV facing the same issue, you can try something like.

```
do_shortcode( '[event post_id="POST_ID"]#_ADDBOOKINGFORM[/event]' ); // replace POST_ID with current post ID
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

These placeholders will only show if bookings are enabled for the given event and in the events manager settings page. Spaces placeholders will default to 0

Comment: i enabled but what is the proper way to use shorcode/placeholder #_ADDBOOKINGFORM

Comment: http://wp-events-plugin.com/documentation/set-up-event-bookings/ go on this link to get your all answers and after that see the example at the bottom of this link http://wp-events-plugin.com/documentation/placeholders/